# Can't delete rows in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, delete-row, corresponding-records

I'm using a form with multiple checkboxes to select several rows and delete all of them, the code I use for that is:

```
foreach ($_POST as $valor){
    $del_user = $_POST["borrar_usuario"];
    $q_borrar = "delete from usuarios where id_user in ('$del_user')";
    mysqli_query($con, $q_borrar);
    echo "usuario borrado";
    header('refresh: 3; url= exito.php');
}
```

But it does not delete anything. Any help, please?

Comment: Print out `$q_borrar`. You'll see it is probably incorrect MySQL. Also, you are open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: what is the use of $valor

Comment: add `mysqli_query($con, $q_borrar) or die(mysqli_error());`

Answer (score 0):

These things?

```
foreach ($_POST["borrar_usuario"] as $valor){
    $del_user = $valor;
    $q_borrar = "delete from usuarios where id_user in ('$del_user')";
    mysqli_query($con, $q_borrar);
    echo "usuario borrado";
    header('refresh: 3; url= exito.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok since `mysql_query` accepts two parameter query and link you misplaced them, it should be:

```
mysqli_query($q_borrar, $con);
```

Also I would remove `header()` at the end of foreach since it will fire and there is a chance that not all data will be deleted.

This is all assuming your $deluser variable is ok and I would **strongly** suggest escaping all data before your query.

Answer (score 0):

If post['borrar_usuario'] is array then may be you can implode the values in quotes of by

```
// applied mysql_real_escape string
$del_user = array_map( function($var){return mysql_real_escape_string($var); } ,$_POST["borrar_usuario"]);  
$delUserList = implode("','",$del_user)."'";
$q_borrar = "delete from usuarios where id_user in ($delUserList)"; // please check SQL before executing
mysqli_query($con, $q_borrar);
echo "usuario borrado";
header('refresh: 3; url= exito.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place `header()` outside of `foreach()` function.

```
$deleteItems = $_POST['items'];
foreach ($deleteItems as $s)
{
    $str = $s;
    mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM table WHERE id='$str'")or die(mysqli_error($con));
}
header("location: manage_menu.php");
exit();
```